# scan all directories and subdirectories for .php file output filter with grep

Tags: linux, grep, terminal, find

i need to check all php files for error.
so i run this command

```
find . -iname '*.php' -exec php -d error_reporting=1 '{}' \;
```

it works well but i  want to show just output that start with **PHP Fatal error**, and if output start with different word not show it.

```
    find . -iname '*.php' -exec php -d error_reporting=1 '{}' \;  | grep '^PHP Fatal error'
```

this command not working i also see

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   169  100   169    0     0   165k      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--  165k   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   169  100   169    0     0   165k

Comment: You like need to also pass stderr to `grep`: `find ... 2>&1 | grep ...`

Comment: Some (most?) shells, instead of `2>&1 |` you can say `|&`